# PreparedStatement, float values and postgresql

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

**Why PreparedStatement with setFloat gives a different result (with less precision) from direct INSERT ?**

The code below shows the issue:

```
    Connection conn = createConnection();

/* here works as expected */
    String sql = "INSERT INTO teste values (1, -50.505050)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.executeUpdate();

/* below, all values were saved with less precision */
    sql = "INSERT INTO teste values (?, ?)";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ps.setInt(1, 2);
    ps.setFloat(2, -50.505050f);
    ps.executeUpdate();

    ps.setInt(1, 3);
    ps.setFloat(2, (float) -50.505050);
    ps.executeUpdate();

    ps.setInt(1, 4);
    ps.setFloat(2, Float.valueOf(-50.505050f));
    ps.executeUpdate();

    ps.setInt(1, 5);
    ps.setFloat(2, Float.valueOf("-50.505050"));
    ps.executeUpdate();

// with double works ok, but how? //
    ps.setInt(1, 6);
    ps.setDouble(2, -50.505050);
    ps.executeUpdate();

    ps.close();
    conn.close();
```

The database is PostgreSQL, with two columns, an id (bigint) and valor (numeric (9,6)).

Here is the output, from pgadmin4.

[image: pgadmin4 and saved data]

The only relevant dependency in pom.xml is below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

The script I used for CREATE the table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.teste
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    valor numeric(9,6),
    CONSTRAINT teste_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.teste
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I am using Java 11.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just included.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a floating point datatype to insert a value to an exact numeric column? Using `BigDecimal` would be more appropriate, and if you really need to use floating point types, use `double`, not `float`.

Comment: I didn't know about the small precision of float types (java). BigDecimal is new to me too. Thanks for the tips !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float` has [from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).
A `double` has [from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).
`-50.505050` is 8 digits, which skirts the limit of what a `float` can handle.

You can see this for yourself if you print it.

```java
System.out.printf("%.6f%n", -50.505050f);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(-50.505050f));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(-50.505050d));
```

*Output*

```
-50.505051
-50.5050506591796875
-50.5050499999999971123543218709528446197509765625
```

The database type `numeric(9,6)` should be stored in Java as a `BigDecimal`. Alternatively, a `double` can be used, but `float` doesn't have the significant decimal digits precision needed to store such values.

Unless you are *severely* constrained by Java memory (extremely rare), never use `float`. With only 6 digits of precision guaranteed, it is simply not useful/reliable, so don't use it.

Comment: Thanks. I will use double from now. I did not understand something: if float can handle 6 digits of precision, why -50.505050 didn't work out?

Comment: @LucianoBrum Because it is an **8**-digit number. Note, that the 6-9 *significant* decimal digits precision is the total number of digits, not just the fractional digits to the right of the decimal point.